how to make an extension which checks if the active tab matches a url everytime the active tab changes
function checkTabURL() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        // tabs is an array of all open tabs in the current window
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        var url = activeTab.url;
        if (url.includes("example.com")) {
            console.log("The active tab's URL matches 'example.com'");
        } else {
            console.log("The active tab's URL does not match 'example.com'");
        }
    });
}

checkTabURL();

setInterval(checkTabURL, 5000); // Adjust the interval as needed (in milliseconds)

this is my code. it works once and then throws this error. how do i change this code to instead make it check the url everytime the active tab changes and resolve this error
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')
    at <URL>



Remove setInterval and chrome.tabs.query, then use chrome.tabs.onActivated listener which provides tabId parameter, see the examples in the documentation. 2) Add "tabs" to "permissions" in manifest.json to see the url.

